# Using TableCell for adding html code to display image type byte[] in C# code behind

Tags: c#, image, pdf, bitmap, tablecell

I have created a template on my c# code by Table and TableCells  - system Windows document,
it is going to generate a PDF file based on the template, now I need to add an image that comes from the database by type byte[] , I believe I can use HTML code to display the image, but when I add the html text in the table cells, it is showing the simple text! and there is no HTML property for that!
I am wondering if anyone knows how can I add the image (bitmap format) to the TableCell.

I tried diffeent codes on tableCell

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.